What's the Norton SI of my new PC?
In the field, the benchmark I used everywhere was the Norton Utilities Sysinfo Benchmark.

It measured computer power in units of IBM PC horsepower. So the 8088 PC got an SI of 1. The AT had an SI of 4. My 386 had an amazing SI of 20.
Eventually, SI stopped working -- presumably because it was counting how often it could do something in one it second, and the counter overflowed. Either that, or it did the same thing a fixed number of times, and the elapsed seconds rounded to zero.
Does anyone know what caused SI to crash on fast machines? It might have been that The horizontal scale of the display overflowed at 55, and Peter couldn't rescale the text mode display.
He couldn't rewrite the benchmark for fast machines because on slower machines, it would give different results than it used to.
The PC was 4.77 MHz, and the PC I just ordered a few minutes ago is 5.1 GHz. So just in terms of pure clock speed, I'm over 1,000 times faster.
But that's too crude. Back then, performance was described in clocks per instruction, and now it's instructions per clock, pipelined and branch-predicted.
In 2001, I used an ad for an old computer that gave performance in SI and also a more recent benchmark, and I used it as a Rosetta Stone to figure that my 2001 computer had an SI of about 4,000.
So what would be the Norton SI of my new Ryzen 7000-series computer? How much PC horsepower is it? Is there another way to estimate this?

That's an interesting question, but very hard to answer without documentation how the original SI was calculated. More open and well-known benchmark numerics like Dhrystone or Whetstone are a lot easier to calculate and compare.

I think your Ryzen 7000 computer is too recent to be on-topic on Retrocomputing.SE.

@OmarandLorraine it's about Norton sysinfo for dos

According to https://dosbenchmark.wordpress.com/research/norton-si/ it simply measures the time to execute 100 iterations of a loop doing a multiplication and divisions

Have you tried running SI on your new system? At least the version in Norton Utilities 8.0 can deal with systems far faster than the IBM PC. You probably won’t be able to boot DOS directly on your Ryzen, but if you run QEMU on Linux using KVM, the benchmark loop will run on-CPU with no translation. I get 950 on an 11-year-old 3.4GHz Haswell Xeon E3.

So, at a quick first approximation from agners tables, assuming cache can keep up, the dominating factor of that loop will be the issue latency of the idiv, at one every 4 cycles for roughly 400 cycles to execute the loop. Or somewhere on the order of 80ns at nominal clock speed. No idea how to turn that into a score though.

@user1937198 >" No idea how to turn that into a score though." Well, you normalize it for the IBM PC. Run it on an 8088, and whatever the score is, that's  SI 1.

@StephenKitt >"Have you tried running SI on your new system?" == Yes, It declines to run in a DOS window. Complains about the 64 bit environment.

@JessFuckett yes, you won’t be able to run it in a plain “DOS” window in Windows. That’s why I explained how you could get it to work ;-).

Well you said I can't boot DOS on my Ryzen, and I'm not going to install another OS just for Peter Norton. Why won't it boot DOS? UEFI?

@JessFuckett I said it probably won’t boot. DOS needs BIOS, and that’s only available through CSM on UEFI systems. Many recent systems don’t provide a CSM, but you could try a FreeDOS USB stick with SI on it.

The algorithm used by the benchmark is clearly on-topic, and the comment by @AlanBirtles shows it’s answerable. If the question is rephrased to focus primarily on that, I’d be willing to vote to reopen it.

I'm not going to install another OS just for Peter Norton. Actually, that is the kind of thing that Retrocomputing people actually do. Either you care about the issue (however esoteric it may be) enough to put effort into it, or you don't.

@user3840170 While Nortons SI is clearly on topic, the question does clearly ask about it's application on a (not specified) modern CPU. So target is neither algorithm nor the benchmark in general.

The link given above by @AlanBirtles has the actual assembly code of the benchmark, so you could simply run it within an ordinary user application on any operating system.

Should run in a dos box on a 32-bit windows 10

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen a counter overflows and crashes

Okok, should start under Win 10 32-bit.  I concur with The others who say you should use dhrystone or similar.

Well if the code simply cannot run on newer processors, they may be right.  You may want to reconsider your approach.
